# Where do I get the wider arduino pro micro from?

Tags: arduino-pro-micro

I have a bunch of boards already fabricated for a game controller that uses the arduino pro micro. I ran out of the arduinos and ordered more. But the new ones are 0.6" wide from pin to pin, and my boards are 0.8". I got narrower pro micros. Now that I'm looking for it online they all seem to be the narrower ones. Same pinout, but they have a smaller version of the MEGA32U4. It also had a USB mini connector instead of USB micro, but for my purposes that doesn't really matter.

Does anyone know where I can get the older 0.8" width version?

Comment: It's open source. Make them yourself?

Comment: Thanks, and I could, but the point was to not have to remake my other boards. I've already updated the controller board to fit the new pro micro size. It would be easier to just make more of them than to build more pro micros. It has fewer components.

Comment: If you are going through the trouble of building a custom board, why integrate a _development_ board, i.e. the micro; instead you should just make the boards to implement the AVR chip directly. This is what _development_ boards are for; the micros probably cost 4x or more than the parts on them.

Comment: Micro PCB is narrower then Pro Micro PCB

Comment: Please add URL's to stuff you refers to!

Comment: Where do you live? ebay appear to have some wider ones (https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Pro-Micro-ATmega32U4-5V-16MHz-Replace-ATmega328-Arduino-Pro-Mini-/191673953805)